# Changing js variable from different script

Tags: javascript, variables

[duplicate]
I downloaded a demo project of pictures slides, and in it i found the variable that controls the delay between images. I want to change the variable dynamically throgh a js i wrote. 
So my question is: is it possible to change a value of a variable from a different script ?
I'm looking for general answer, not specific to my codem therefore I'm not posting it.

reserch I did for (Michael Laszlo) : searching in google - I didnt find any results relevant to me excpet one that I didnt understand.

Thank you!

update:
I want to cahnge the var delay

```
   (function($){
    flux.slider = function(elem, opts) {
        // Setup the flux.browser singleton to perform feature detection
        flux.browser.init();

        if(!flux.browser.supportsTransitions)
        {
            if(window.console && window.console.error)
                console.error("Flux Slider requires a browser that supports CSS3 transitions");
        }

        var _this = this;

        this.element = $(elem);

        // Make a list of all available transitions
        this.transitions = [];
        for(var fx in flux.transitions)
            this.transitions.push(fx);

        this.options = $.extend({
            autoplay: true,
            transitions: this.transitions,
            delay: 10000,
            pagination: true,
            controls: false,
            captions: false,
            width: null ,
            height:null,
            onTransitionEnd: null
        }, opts);
```

}

Comment: General question: is it possible? General answer: it depends. :)

Comment: Without knowing the scope of the variable we can't help you. JavaScript variables are function-scoped which means that if the variable is defined within a function (or object) you may not be able to access it externally (external to the file, function, object)

Comment: i updated my question to show the scope of the var

Comment: it is a variable inside an object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two scripts are on the same page, and if the value to change is global, then it's possible.
Like:

```
<script>
  var variable = value1
  var function1 = function() {
    var variable2 =value8
  }
</script>
[Some html here]
<script>
  variable = value2
</script>
```

Variable2 is not accessible because it was declared in a function (thus only acessible from that function).

Comment: the scripts arent on the same page

Comment: The code example you showed is a type definition. Modify "delay: 10000," to refer to a global scope variable. you will then be able to modify this variable from some other script.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little. I didnt understand